# Ruby: transform a data structure into an excel sheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have processed  a log file and created a data structure of below format

```
values = [ {:VM=>"VM_US_OLA_1"}
{:id=>"OLFTB51", :datum=>{"LAP"=>"6.93817", "YCC_OWER"=>"1.0391"}}
{:id=>"OLFTB10", :datum=>{"LAP_2"=>"2.72646", "CFG_ON"=>"15.9489746", "YCC_ON"=>".401794"}}

{:VM=>"VM_ASIA_FLO_1"}
{:id=>"LOPMLAP", :datum=>{"LAP"=>"1.81048584", "FM_ON"=>".00"} ]
```

values is an array.

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet of below format where only the VM column gets highlighted in green and for every VM set, a blank line highlighted in 'yellow' should be inserted. I tried multiple approaches and went thru the axlsx documentation too but unable to get the desired format.

My excel snippet below:

```
require 'axlsx'
p = Axlsx::Package.new

p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "Statistics") do |sheet|
    style1 = sheet.styles.add_style(:bg_color => "EF0920", :fg_color => "FFFFFF", b:true)
    style2 = sheet.styles.add_style(:bg_color => "00FF00", :fg_color => "FFFFFF", b:true)
    sheet.add_row ["VM", "NAME", "DETAILS", "OCC"], :style => style1
    values.each do |val|
      sheet.add_row [ val[:VM], val[:id] ], :style =>[style2, nil]
      val[:datum].each do |k, v|
        sheet << ["", "",  k, v]        
       end 
         end
    sheet.add_row
end

p.serialize 'Stat.xlsx'
```

Any suggestions should be really helpful here, many thanks.

**Expected Output**

[image]

**Current Output**

[image]

Adding Log file and my code

Log

```
        ---- vm name ----
        VM_US_OLA_1

        OLFTB51


        OWNER                   IN_GB
        ------------------------------ ----------
        LAP                    6.93817
        YCC_OWER               1.0391

        =========================================


        ---- vm name ----


        OLFTB10


        OWNER                   IN_GB
        ------------------------------ ----------
        LAP_2                  2.7266846
        CFG_ON                 15.9489746
        YCC_ON                .401794


        =========================================


        ---- vm name ----
        VM_ASIA_FLO_1

        LOPMLAP


        OWNER                   IN_GB
        ------------------------------ ----------
        LAP                1.81048584
        FM_ON              .00


        =========================================


        ---- vm name ----

        INGTY_2


        OWNER                   IN_GB
        ------------------------------ ----------

  =========================================

    so on of the same format
```

Code to process the logs

```
require 'csv'

values = []

total = File.read("final.log")
total.each_line do |line|
  line.strip!
  next if line.empty?
  next if line.include?('selected') || line.include?('IN_GB')
  next if ['-','='].include? line[0]
  parts = line.split ' '
   if parts.size == 1 and line.start_with?('size')
    values[current += 1] = {vm: line.strip}
    next
  elsif parts.size == 1 and parts = /^(?!.*size_).*$/
    values[current += 1] = {id: line, datum: {}}
    next
  end

  parts.each_cons(2) do |key, value|
    values[current][:datum][key] = value 
    end
end

puts values
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the structure of your data. Try to change to have the values of your array in this structure

`{:VM=>"VM_US_OLA_1", :id=>"OLFTB51", :datum=>{"LAP"=>"6.93817", "YCC_OWER"=>"1.0391"}`

What's happening is `VM` is one record in your array, and the other data is another record in the array, you need to merge them so you access them in the same loop iteration

**EDIT**

I guess how we parse the log file is a bit tricky, so I am going to leave it but I am sure that this part I am going to introduce can be done in the log file parsing

First, we can change the structure of the array like that (before `p.workbook.add_worksheet`)

```
dataset = []
values.each_with_index do |value|
    if value[:VM].present? # or :vm, not sure about the key
        dataset << value
        dataset.last[:data] = []
    else 
        dataset.last[:data] << value
    end
end
```

Then this loop: `values.each do |val|`

Can be changed to `dataset.each do |val|`

Then you can continue with the rest of your logic:

```
  sheet.add_row [ val[:VM], val[:data][0][:id] ], :style =>[style2, nil]
  val[data].each do |record|
    record[:datanum].each do |k, v|
```

The problem with your previous code is, you used to add a new row `sheet.add_row` at the end of each iteration, so this was messing things up as you were expecting the data you need to be just right after your `VM` but a new line has already been inserted

Comment: @amdruid: Is there any method like array flatten method. I went thru the array of hash Ruby docs. but I couldn't exactly locate the same, thanks.

Comment: There is, but before we proceed I think it'll be better to show how you process the log file. Maybe we can find a quick trick to create the correct structure from there

Comment: Thanks for your time here !! I have edited my question with the Log entries and the code..

Comment: Thank you for providing more context, I updated my answer. And good job with parsing part of the log! You can even do better than I suggested in there I believe

Comment: @amrduid: Really appreciate your help here, many thanks.. Got an issue, following line `sheet.add_row [ val[:VM], val[:data][0][:id] ], :style =>[style2, nil]`  prints only the 1st id. say it prints only OLFTB51 and not OLFTB10 or the following ids..

Comment: You got the rest of the ids in each `record`, you can print them it here `sheet << [record[:id], "",  k, v]` . Let me know if this works

Comment: It prints the remaining ids as hash in the excel sheet